# Bolt tensile load through an "intermediary"?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, civil-engineering, automotive-engineering, bolting, tension

Following up on this [question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/45875/tensile-force-on-line-of-bolts), does it change anything if the bolted arm is an intermediate arm (e.g. some sort of mating interface like below)? That is, the arm receiving the load is connected to the original arm through a different set of bolts?

[image]

I applied the cantilever method from the original question to the "arm and mounting plate" to determine B4 and B5, and applied the same method to the "mounting surface" and the "rigid body" treatment of the "mounting plate" and the "arm" to determine B1 .. B3. But, I don't know if I can ignore this intermediary like this.

- Can I treat the bottom two components as a "rigid body" and use the cantilever method?
- Does the location of the arm along the mounting plate change anything on B1 B2 B3?
- What would be the forces on B1 .. B5?

(EDIT) To add some specifics:

1. The "main surface" to which all of this is bolted are aluminum C channel beams, about 1.5 x 3 x 3/16" about 8' in length spaced at 12" apart, which is why I want to spread the load on each (e.g. at each bolt location, I can add multiple bolts along the length).
2. The "mounting plate" is planned to be a 1' x 2' x 1/2" aluminum plate, with an 8 bolt pattern (e.g. 3 bolts at B1, 2 at B2 and 3 at B3 location). Based on the loads, I can make this larger or smaller (both in area or thickness).
3. The "arm" is a 5000 lbs rated step/bumper hitch receiver with an arm attached (i.e. basically like a wheel barrow or 2nd class lever), with 4 bolts, to be mated to the "mounting plate" (2). There will be no (or minimal) shear forces on this hitch, only tension.

Based on these I'm trying to achieve/determine a few things:

- Reduce/spread the load on the C channels (i.e. "main surface")
- Make sure I use the right size "mounting plate" (e.g. should it be thicker or larger? Different material?)
- Figure out whether the location of the arm along the mounting plate matters or not

I have also used SimPHY to model this out with distance connectors for the bolts, but I don't want to rely on those simulations since it seems to be geared for more general purpose interactions. While the tension on the bottom two surfaces seemed about the right, I am doubtful about the tension on simulated for "bolts" B1 .. B3.

Comment: You need to show what you have considered so far.

Comment: I would presume this setup will be more flexible under load than the one without the mating interface. Are you ok with separation of the plates when loaded? If not, prestressing the bolts might help, but it will of course increase forces in the bolts.

Comment: @SolarMike I'm unclear about the "what have you considered so far" comment, can you clarify? Do you mean like the arm receiving the load and the mating interface are highly rigid?

Comment: @TomášLétal how much separation, but in general not concerned. I've added some specifics, in case that helps to the original question.

Comment: So what theory / equations that you found in the other question have you applied to this situation? People on here tend to like seeing effort...

Comment: Ah, I see, I'll add to the question. I basically applied the cantilever method to the "arm and mounting plate" to determine B4 and B4, and applied the same method to  the mounting surface and the "rigid body" treatment of the "mounting plate" and the "arm". However, I'm not sure this is correct, which why the question is about this "intermediary mating surface" primarily.

Comment: "Does it change anything?"  Yes, changing the design changes the design.  You have additional points of analysis.  B5 & B3 are the bolts to worry about.

Comment: @TigerGuy really? I would have thought most of the load would be taken by B1 and B4, since B3 and B5 are essentially the fulcrums in the two systems (if I treat them separately). What I don't know is how the position of the arm along the mounting plate effects B1/B2.

Comment: @TechieJ you're right, I had my force reversed.